How to create dynamic response with json in wiremock
{   "result": {     {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.ids') as |id|}}"{{id}}": {       "favorite_0": 1,       "search_0": 1,       "visit_0": 1,       "order_0": 1,       "basket_0": 1,       "jfyimpression_0": 1     }{{#unless @last}}     ,{{/unless}}{{/each}}   },   "messages": [     {       "type": "success",       "position": "top",       "content": "Request processed successfully.",       "title": "All is well!",       "code": "SUCCESS_1001"     }   ] }

I created this response for dynamically replicate result for every id. Id list can have be one or multiple item. Depend on the ids result > ids will change.
I tried this json but it didn't help, how to create json for it to be dynamic
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/api/v1/feature-store/features",
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.feature_name",
            "equalTo": "customer-product_clickstream_activities_precomputed"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.identifier",
            "equalTo": "123972627"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.features",
            "contains": "visit_0"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.features",
            "contains": "search_0"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.features",
            "contains": "favorite_0"
          },
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.ids",
            "contains": "\\d{9}"
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "jsonBody": {
          "result": "{{{#each (jsonPath request.body ',$.ids') as |id index|}}  {{id}}: {\n    \"favorite_{{index}}\": 1,\n    \"search_{{index}}\": 1,\n    \"visit_{{index}}\": 1,\n    \"order_{{index}}\": 1,\n    \"basket_{{index}}\": 1,\n    \"jfyimpression_{{index}}\": 1\n  }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}{{/each}}}",
          "messages": [
            {
              "type": "success",
              "position": "top",
              "content": "Request processed successfully.",
              "title": "All is well!",
              "code": "SUCCESS_1001"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


I setup a simple mapping to help figure out the response templating.  Here is the mapping I am using:
{
  "name": "ids",
  "request": {
    "url": "/api/v1/feature-store/features",
    "method": "POST"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "features.txt",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ]
  }
}

This file is in my mappings folder and has a couple of key points to it.  First, the body is stored in a separate file called features.txt which is saved in the __files directory.  The second thing is that it has the response templating transformer enabled.
The features.txt file looks like this:
{
  "result": {     
  {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.ids') as |id index|}}
    "{{id}}": {
      "favorite_{{index}}": 1, 
      "search_{{index}}": 1, 
      "visit_{{index}}": 1, 
      "order_{{index}}": 1, 
      "basket_{{index}}": 1, 
      "jfyimpression_{{index}}": 1     
    }{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}
  {{/each}}
}, 
"messages": [
    {
      "type": "success", 
      "position": "top", 
      "content": "Request processed successfully.", 
      "title": "All is well!", 
      "code": "SUCCESS_1001"
    }
  ]
}

It loops through the ids in the request and updates the response accordingly.  With a request like this:
{
  "ids": [1,2]
}

It will produce a response like this:
{
  "result": {
    "1": {
      "favorite_0": 1,
      "search_0": 1,
      "visit_0": 1,
      "order_0": 1,
      "basket_0": 1,
      "jfyimpression_0": 1
    },
    "2": {
      "favorite_1": 1,
      "search_1": 1,
      "visit_1": 1,
      "order_1": 1,
      "basket_1": 1,
      "jfyimpression_1": 1
    }
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "success",
      "position": "top",
      "content": "Request processed successfully.",
      "title": "All is well!",
      "code": "SUCCESS_1001"
    }
  ]
}

Update:
If you don't want to separate the response body into a separate file you can include it in the WireMock mapping file.  The only difference is that you would use the body element instead of the bodyFileName element.  As the WireMock mapping file needs to be valid json, all the response body will need to be escaped like the following:
{
  "name": "ids",
  "request": {
    "url": "/api/v1/feature-store/features",
    "method": "POST"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{ \"result\": { {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.ids') as |id index|}} \"{{id}}\": { \"favorite_{{index}}\": 1, \"search_{{index}}\": 1, \"visit_{{index}}\": 1, \"order_{{index}}\": 1, \"basket_{{index}}\": 1, \"jfyimpression_{{index}}\": 1 }{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}} {{/each}} }, \"messages\": [ { \"type\": \"success\", \"position\": \"top\", \"content\": \"Request processed successfully.\", \"title\": \"All is well!\", \"code\": \"SUCCESS_1001\" } ] }",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ]
  }
}


thank you this is a great way to do it, unfortunately ı need this whole mapping as a json because I can only upload mapping as a json and mock process need the start with API not with the automation. If you know a way to do it as a whole json, it will be perfect!!

That should be possible. Instead of the separate file referenced via the bodyFileName element in the mapping json, you could include the whole thing in the body element. This isn’t as convenient because it means you have to escape the quotes etc to make it valid json.

yes i didnt make it a valid json and ı don't know how to

It is largely just escaping all the quotes - "body": "{\"message\": \"Hello, World!\"}"

{{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.ids') as |id index|}} // I am struggling to make this a valid json, can you help me with this txt. I am trying to correct this for days

dont know how to do it a valid json and in a way that wiremock can understand

I have updated the main answer with the WireMock mapping file with the response body included and escaped.  The example I posted works in the tests I have performed so hopefully it will work for you as well
